# is there anyway make my carousel working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, codeigniter-3

i have carousel problem in my personal exercise project, i get these html,css,javascript in internet and trying to wrap it all together.

```js
//Sidebar script start
$(document).ready(function () {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
     isClosed = false;

    trigger.click(function () {
      hamburger_cross();      
    });

    function hamburger_cross() {

      if (isClosed == true) {          
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
      } else {   
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = true;
      }
  }
  
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });  
});
//sidebar script end

//carousel 1 start
$(".carousel").swipe({

  swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {

    if (direction == 'left') $(this).carousel('next');
    if (direction == 'right') $(this).carousel('prev');

  },
  allowPageScroll:"vertical"

});
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
body,
html { height: 100%;}
.nav .open > a, 
.nav .open > a:hover, 
.nav .open > a:focus {background-color: transparent;}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*           Wrappers            */
/*-------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 220px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 220px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -220px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 220px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -220px;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*     Sidebar nav styles        */
/*-------------------------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    position: relative; 
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
      -moz-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
       -ms-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
            transition: width .2s ease-in;

}
.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before {
    background-color: #ec1b5a;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before {
    background-color: #79aefe;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before {
    background-color: #314190;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before {
    background-color: #279636;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6):before {
    background-color: #7d5d81;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before {
    background-color: #ead24c;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before {
    background-color: #2d2366;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before {
    background-color: #35acdf;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
      -moz-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
       -ms-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
            transition: width .2s ease-in;

}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;    
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 44px;
}
.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #222;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*       Hamburger-Cross         */
/*-------------------------------*/

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;  
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
  outline: none;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top { 
  top: 5px; 
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 5px;  
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;  
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle { display: none; }
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
}
.hamburger.is-open:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*            Overlay            */
/*-------------------------------*/

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,.8);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                       Brand
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Works <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown heading</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/maridlcrmn">Follow me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                <span class="hamb-top"></span>
                <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
                <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="scrolling-wrapper row flex-row flex-nowrap mt-4 pb-4 pt-2">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
  
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Bootstrap 3 default carousel with swipe and touch gestures</h1>
    <p class="lead">How to add the swipes gesture to comand the Bootstrap 3 carousel on mobile devices.</p>
    <p>Made by <strong>Andrea Rufo</strong>, more info and tutorial on <a href="http://www.andrearufo.it/">andrearufo.it</a></p>
  </div>
       

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=114">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=62">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=315">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=622">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=401">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

i place css in one place because i still dont know how to link css from "assets" into my "view" in codeigniter 3. i tried carousel from w3school.com and still same, that's all my question. im sorry if i break stackoverflow rules or something i rarely post something here. thank you!

Comment: I see that you are missing some closing tags in the html you provided. I also see you're using JQuery. Any reason for that? W3schools provides a perfectly fine [vanillaJS-example of the carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

Comment: really?? dang i dont realize it...honestly i dont know why it use jquery, like a said that i take the code from internet and a try to wrap it all together. and yeah im still newb, i only know basic html and css. thanks for the w3 link tho,i think i will use it...

Answer (score 1):

Hey for the carousel part [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel) works!

Here is the code :

```css
  /* Make the image fully responsive */
  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/909/500/300.jpg?hmac=UvD9EPaMb3GZwTifQ0TgEcpmU4wlStwXfuzBx3hCqUc" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1075/500/300.jpg?hmac=5DhRFK2dTT-URjGdj3Fgb8fBZOGnqy-lIR1gIm_JJ3U" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/69/500/300.jpg?hmac=3n60xnk-4-IxrqSEIdI9tBUlCBD5rrIyJH7S1fsZ5HU" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And a link too: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tryit.php/LFAQuLWlk6